# Forcing Cells to recalculate in Excel using Macros

Tags: excel, cells, forcing

I am currently working on an excel spreadsheet called Calendar.xlsm
I have Excel2010.

My workbook has the following worksheets:

1. Cover Sheet
2. Calendar
3. Colour Detection
4. Printable

The **"Colour Detection"** sheet uses a User Defined Function to detect the colours of cells on the "**Calendar**" worksheet and based on that colour returns a number for that particular cell; For example if `Calendar!C3` has a fill colour of `"light green"` then `Colour Detection!C3 = 43`

*Just for completeness the UDF is called ColorIndex and was written by **Bob Phillips**.*

I then use conditional formating to colour cells in my "**Printable**" worksheet based on the number stored in "**Colour Detection**".

My problems start when there is a colour change on the "**Calendar**" sheet, usually when this happens **"Colour Detection"** remains unchanged unless I select the cells manually and press return.

My knowledge of how Excel works with Visual Basic in this area is very limited but growing.

My first idea for a solution was to record a macro where I selected each cell and hit return one by one. I then attached the macro to a button called Calculate on the **"Cover Sheet"**. Immediately this didn't work because there are approximately 800 cells that use this UDF.

While trying this I thought I stumbled on the solution, I noticed that if I applied my solution to only a few cells, the whole worksheet seemed to update. I then applied this and tested it a few times and it worked. I then presented my work to a friend as the masterpiece I was sure it was, and while demonstrating it to them it all fell over and only the cells I selected in my macro updated.

Next I tried adding the line

```
Application.Volatile
```

to my UDF but this doesn't to make a difference.

**My question is how do I easily force every single cell in my worksheet to update by doing something simple like pushing a recalculate button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Ctrl-Alt-F9 this forces every formula in the workbook to be calculated. Or you could set workbook.forcefullcalculation to True in your workbook_Open event.